# Diff tool is telling me there is a difference where I don't see one

Tags: linux, diff

When I run the diff tool on a program of mine, I get this:

```
1c1
< (1)$ >> ---
---
> (1)$ >> ---
```

From what I can gather online, this seems like a problem with trailing spaces. However, I've manually checked the output, and I can't find any trailing spaces whatsoever. What could be wrong?

My program's output:

```
(1)$ -${ALPHA}-${BETA}-
>> ---
(2)$
```

Comment: And when you run the output through `od -c`?

Comment: Usually it's a line break that got converted.

Comment: Try using `diff` with the `-w` (ignore all whitespace) option.

Answer (score 0):

Use the option `-B` or `--ignore-blank-lines`. This helps in focusing only on the actual characters/contents and ignoring changes in the number of blank lines between the files.